# differential amplifier mismatch of transistor values

Tags: mosfet, bjt, differential

I am studying differential amplifiers and I am confused that when mismatch occurs in gm or RC in BJTs or gm and RD in mosfets, in book it carries out calculations as if the transistors are matched. When Rc's are not equal, there is no even splitting of emitter currents and different Ic values come up and things change a lot, but the book treats these cases as if Ic's are equal. I am confused. Did not I understand the book well or is this the way?

Comment: In an integrated circuit, the transistors will be well matched. With discrete components, there may be significant mismatches. Generally, op-amps are used with significant negative feedback which tends to erase the imperfections of the circuit. The imperfections of differential pairs often show up as input offset voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correct--a differential amplifier won't work well at all if the transistors aren't well-matched. Fortunately, transistors within an IC are quite well matched, and you can get matched transistor pairs in a single package fairly easily. The matching also relies on the transistors being at the same temperature, too, which is easy if they're on the same silicon die and much less so if they're not.

If you're willing to put in the work, I've seen discrete differential amplifiers get reasonable performance from using transistors selected to be as closely matched as possible, using a curve tracer, and then bonded together for tight thermal coupling (in the particular case I'm thinking of, the two TO-92 packages were glued together face-to-face). Even so, it wasn't as good a differential amplifier as you could make using a single-package matched pair.